# React-Helmet Parent component <title> taking priority

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-helmet

I have an app that loads data asynchronously and uses Helmet.
I have a  component in App.js, and in a child component Category.js.

Whenever category gets enough data that it can update the page  attribute, I expect that the child's Helmet component will override the App's title tag.

In **App.js'** render() method:

```js
<Helmet
 onChangeClientState={(newState) => console.log('Change app:', newState, 'Title: ' + this.props.siteInfo.site.title)}
 title={this.props.siteInfo.site.title}
>
 <meta property="twitter:title" content={this.props.siteInfo.site.title} />
 {urlTag}
 {linkTag}
 <meta property="og:title" content={this.props.siteInfo.site.title} />
 <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
 <meta property="og:description" content={this.props.siteInfo.site.title} />
 {favicons.map(icon => {
  return icon
 })}
</Helmet>
```

In **Category.js'** render() method:

```js
<Helmet
 onChangeClientState={(newState) => console.log('Change category:', newState, 'Title: ' + title)}
 title={title}
>
 <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
 <meta property="og:description" content={title} />
 <meta property="twitter:title" content={title} />
</Helmet>
```

If I reload a category route, I expect the title tag to be the category once it's data comes back from the API.  However it is always the site title rendered in App.  I can see this because the App's `onChangeClientState` function is the last thing logged in the console.  I would expect the Category's `onChangeClientState` to fire last.

If I navigate around the site a bit (go to the homepage and back to the category) the result is what I expect.  However, on a simple page refresh, the child component doesn't render it's Helmet title.

I think I'm misunderstanding the flow of data within Helmet